# Method for solving $\frac{dy}{dx} = 2xy+2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried using the integrating factor method, since the equation is first order linear: suppose $R$ is the integrating factor. We have

$\log(R) = \displaystyle \int -2x dx = -x^2+c_0$

so $R = c_1 e^{-x^2}$

Then $e^{x^2}y = \displaystyle \int 2e^{-x^2} dx$ so $y = \dfrac{\displaystyle \int 2e^{-x^2} dx}{e^{-x^2}}$

I also tried using Laplace transforms but I obtained a similar differential equation. Is there another method that can be used to solve this?

Comment: Nothing wrong with $y_p(x) = e^{x^2} \int_0^x 2e^{-t^2} \ dt$ as a particular solution. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: I'm ok with leaving it in that form, I just wanted to see if I was missing an easier approach. Thanks!

Comment: The constants look right to me. And yes, it's the error function times $\sqrt{\pi}$

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct nad, as said in comments, you can finish the problem. Suppose you make $y=e^{x^2}z$, the equation just becomes $e^{x^2} z'-2=0$ and then $$z=\int 2 e^{-x^2} dx=\sqrt{\pi }~ \text{erf}(x)+C$$ and finally $$y=e^{x^2} \Big(C+\sqrt{\pi }~ \text{erf}(x)\Big)$$